# Export Excel sheets and send them as emails (Loop)

Tags: excel, vba, email

[image]

I'm trying to automate a report production and distribution process. What I need to do is create a macro that goes through the list (1 to 20) and for each row creates a new file (separate Excel file), pastes 2 tabs from the current one (sheet names are in columns J and K) and saves it under the filename in column E. Then the macro should open Outlook and create an email by attaching the file and using the subject, distribution list, email body as shown in the table.

I'd highly appreciate any help as I've been bumping my head with this for a while.

---

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked before. I've tried to combine code that addresses different parts of this process. So far I have the following:

```
enter code here
Sub Create_Files()

Dim MyDateStr As String
Dim wkbCurrent As Workbook
Dim wkbtemp As Workbook
Dim wkbtemp2 As Workbook
Dim MyLocation As String
Dim SheetName As String

Set wkbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
MyDateStr = wkbCurrent.Sheets("Control").Range("F12")

ChDir "W:\Finance Analysis\Contsys2\DATA\aacorpfinance\_yr 2017\Expense    reports\"
  If Len(Dir(MyDateStr, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir (MyDateStr)
End If

MyLocation = "W:\Finance Analysis\Contsys2\DATA\aacorpfinance\_yr 2017\Expense reports\"

 SheetName = wkbCurrent.Sheets("Emails").Range("C2")

 Set wkbtemp = Workbooks.Add

 wkbCurrent.Sheets(SheetName).Cells.Select


 With wkbtemp
 wkbtemp.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial



 wkbCurrent.Sheets("M & A").Copy
 wkbtemp2.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

 Set wkbtemp = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

 End Sub
```

I haven't reached the loop and emails part but I have some code that I found elsewhere that I am trying to use as a basis.

Comment: Show us what you already tried. And try to do it step by step. Dozens of similar questions have been asked before, so there is plenty of code around to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

here is some code to get you started

it loops through all the cells on all the rows

just add routines to create emails, do attachments, save files, etc.

```
Option Explicit

Sub exportIntoEmails()

    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("a1:a20")

        Debug.Print "file", rng.Columns("b").Value
        Debug.Print "folder", rng.Columns("d").Value
        Debug.Print "filename", rng.Columns("e").Value
        Debug.Print "subject", rng.Columns("f").Value
        Debug.Print "dist. list", rng.Columns("g").Hyperlinks(1).Address
        Debug.Print "cc list", Replace(rng.Columns("h").Hyperlinks(1).Address, "mailto:", "")
        Debug.Print "email body", rng.Columns("i").Value

        Dim aaa As Range
        For Each aaa In rng.Columns("j").Resize(1, 2)
            Debug.Print "attach", aaa.Value
        Next aaa

    Next rng
End Sub
```